# Need a solution to Retrieve data from Excel in C# without HRESULT:0x800A03EC exception

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com-interop

I need to retrieve data from an Excel file and insert the data into a database. Im trying now to just retrieve the data but i keep getting an HRESULT:0x800A03EC exception error.

my code:

```
  public void ReadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                Excel.Application ep = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook ewb = ep.Workbooks.Open(@"C:/Temp/Copy of AGCO Transport Schedule.xlsx");
                Excel.Worksheet ews = ewb.Sheets[1];
                Excel.Range range = ews.UsedRange;

                int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
                int columnCount = range.Columns.Count;

                for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < columnCount; j++)
                    {
                      string  str = (string)(range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                        Console.WriteLine(str);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YOLO "+e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

After getting the solution for the code above from a user here. The loop indexes should be changed to 1 instead of 0. I have corrected the code above. But the thing is that I need to select only 2 columns from the data in Excel, so i went on using sql for retrieving the data from the Excel file. But this time i keep getting "failed to create file" error and this happens when i try to open my connection.

my code:

```
public void ReadExcelFile()
{
    string connectionString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExcelConnection"].ConnectionString.Replace("'", "\""), "@C:/Temp/Copy.xlsx");
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlCmd = "SELECT  * FROM [Ark1$]";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR in ReadExcelFile() method. Error Message : " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the exception, which line?

Comment: The error code `0x800A03EC` (or -2146827284) means NAME_NOT_FOUND; in other words, you've asked for something, and Excel can't find it.

Comment: Check this post please: It seems the error is due to [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkbookClass.SaveAs line](http://www.hagrin.com/319/exception-hresult-0x800a03ec-excel-net-sql-and-windows-server-2008)

Ref: Other knowledge based [Stack posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Exception+from+HRESULT%3A+0x800A03EC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something i would like to add:
Your method is SLOW - really, really slow.
To speed it up, you have two alternatives:
Use EPPLUS, it is a fast and free library for excel reading/writing.
Oder get the data from excel in one go, simply "pull" the data from your range object into an array (dim values() = range.value2 in VB.net) and iterate over that array. That is a lot faster than enumerating each cell.

Comment: But EPPLUS (and any library based on OpenXML) will only load Excel 2007 files and up. Old .XLS file are not compatible. I can`t remember the name of the InterOp library helper that makes things so much easier...

Comment: i have edited the question and code. are you able to help me with this ?

Answer (score 3):

Try by starting loop counting from 1 on both for loops. Index for excel file is starting from  1. I'ts not zero based index i suppose.

Comment: That is correct - mot Excel indexes starts at 1. It's exteremely annoying so keep it in mind - it can generate thausands of little bugs. Addtionally, STOP looping at usedrange.rows.count